# Launching a node crashes Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using ROS Groovy on two different machines in a cluster setup.

I have been trying to set up a system where I start a roscore on my local machine (Mac OSX 10.7.5) and then on a server machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server, I start another node.  This works the first few times, but eventually the server machine goes into some sort of kernel core dump (I don't have access to the physical machine to get this core dump) and requires a manual restart. My local machine seems unaffected.

My question is if Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server has problems running ROS nodes or if this is an isolated incident only for my setup.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Some more details about my situation.  I am starting only a roscore on my local machine where I load a set of parameters to the parameter server.  I then start a custom written node on the server machine using a Sun Grid Engine qsub containing the roslaunch file.  The first time I do this, it works okay. The second time, if the node is launched on the same server machine, it causes the error above.

After fiddling with it some more, I found that restarting the roscore on my local machine between each qsub alleviates this problem.  Is it possible that having nodes connecting to the same rosmaster over time is unstable?

I did run a roswtf and got the following error:

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /custom_node_name->/rosout (/rosout)

The node was able to read the parameters so the ROS_MASTER_URI is configured correctly I believe.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66425/launching-a-node-crashes-ubuntu-12.04-lts-server/) by [robotzak](https://answers.ros.org/users/5304/robotzak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-03**:
It might help to know which nodes you are running, like if there could be any graphics involved, in case you have a bad graphics or headless server. And if running `roswtf`on both machines finds anything interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it might be a problem with the NFS system that is set up on the cluster.  I'm not entirely sure it's a ROS specific problem.

---

Originally posted by [robotzak](https://answers.ros.org/users/5304/robotzak/) with karma: 36 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0